What can I say about $P(B|A_1 \cap A_2)$ if I know that $P(B|A_1), P(B|A_2) \approx 1$?
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space and $A_1,A_2,B \in \Sigma$. Define $P(B|A_1) = E(\chi_{B}|A_1)$. From real life, I have experience that if there are two numbers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \approx 1$ such that $P(B|A_1) = \alpha_1$ and $P(B|A_2) = \alpha_2$, then $\alpha = P(B|A_1\cap A_2)$ is even closer to 1 than both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.
I am interested in estimates of how close $\alpha$ might be to 1, depending on assumptions put on $A_1$ and $A_2$.

If it's possible to treat the $A_i$s as 'random sets', and defining 'a notion' of the expectation of $\alpha$, that would be interesting.
I have the impression that how close I expect $\alpha$ to 1 in real life situations tend to depend on how much of $A_1 \setminus A_2$ is contained in $B$, but interested in why that intuition exists.

I'm sure these questions have been studied, because we're used to thinking about this as children. What is the name of the theory I'm looking for? Can you recommend a text which I can use to learn more about it?

EDIT: Here is an example of what I mean in case it is unclear:
Assume you're a cancer doctor interested in the probability that a cancer is fatal ($B$). If you a see a patient and he has a particular kind of cancer ($A_1$), then the probability it's fatal is $\alpha_1$. If you see a patient with a different kind of cancer ($A_2$), the probability that it's fatal is some other number $\alpha_2$. Let's arbitrarily assume $\alpha_2\geq\alpha_1$. What happens if you see a patient with both these cancers? What is the probability that this patient dies? That is $\alpha$. You can see trivially that $\alpha$ is bigger than both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in this case. I'm looking for the theory to learn how assumptions about $A_1$ and $A_2$ relates to $\alpha$.

It is not that simple even in your cancer example. For instance, imagine a hypothetical scenario in which two cancers magically suppress each other and render themselves less detrimental. This condition should be rare, but when it happens, the patient somehow have much better chance of surviving. Under such a scenario, the probability $\mathbf{P}(B\mid A_1\cap A_2)$ can be small even if $\mathbf{P}(B\mid A_1)$ and $\mathbf{P}(B\mid A_2)$ are large. This tells that we require some extra assumptions on $A_1$ and $A_2$ (such as large overlap, independence, etc.) is necessary.

Did I not write that twice? I cite myself:

«I am interested in estimates of how close $\alpha$ might be to 1, depending on assumptions put on $A_1$ and $A_2$» and;
«I'm looking for the theory to learn how assumptions about $A_1$ and $A_2$ relates to $\alpha$.»


The general principle that you are suggesting is not true. Here is an example. Suppose I am the greatest chess player that ever lived. I have two students. They will be attending a conference with 998 other chess players. I know for a fact that my students are better than the other 998, by far. At the end of the conference, there is an unofficial tradition where 2 students from the 1000 will be chosen at random to face each other. The chosen 2 will wager \$100 on the game. My students are broke, so I give them each \$100, in case they are chosen. At the end of the conference, if they still have the \$100, they will give it back to me, and they will also give me their winnings if they win.
Let
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \text{"My first student is chosen to play."}\\
A_2 &= \text{"My second student is chosen to play."}\\
B &= \text{"My students bring back \$300 altogether."}
\end{align}
Assume either of my students will defeat any of the other 998 with 100% certainty, but that if they play each other, then each is equally likely to win.
If both are chosen to face each other, then one will bring me back \$200 and the other will bring me back \$0. Therefore, $P(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$. On the other hand, if one is chosen and the other is not, then I will receive \$300 upon their return. Therefore,
\begin{align}
P(B \mid A_1) &= P(A_2 \mid A_1) P(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2)
+ P(A_2^c \mid A_1) P(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2^c)\\
&= \frac{1}{999} \cdot 0 + \frac{998}{999} \cdot 1\\
&\approx 0.999
\end{align}
By symmetry, $P(B \mid A_2) = P(B \mid A_1) \approx 0.999$.
In the positive direction, let us add the assumptions that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conditionally independent given $B$, and also conditionally independent given $B^c$. Let us also assume that $P(B) \approx 1/2$. For an event $E$, let $O(E) = P(E)/P(E^c)$ denote the odds of $E$ and $O(E \mid F) = P(E \mid F)/P(E^c \mid F)$. Then $O(B \mid A_1)$ and $O(B \mid A_2)$ are very large real numbers, and $O(B) \approx 1$.
Conditional odds obey the following formula:
$$
O(E \mid F) = O(E) \cdot \frac{P(F \mid E)}{P(F \mid E^c)}.
$$
Using this, we have
\begin{align}
O(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2) &= O(B) \cdot \frac{P(A_1 \cap A_2 \mid B)}{P(A_1 \cap A_2 \mid B^c)}\\
&= O(B) \cdot \frac{P(A_1 \mid B)}{P(A_1 \mid B^c)} \cdot \frac{P(A_2 \mid B)}{P(A_2 \mid B^c)}\\
&= \frac{O(B \mid A_1) O(B \mid A_2)}{O(B)}\\
&\approx O(B \mid A_1) O(B \mid A_2)
\end{align}
Hence, $O(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2)$ is a much larger real number than either $O(B \mid A_1)$ or $O(B \mid A_2)$. Therefore, $P(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2)$ is much closer to 1 than either $P(B \mid A_1)$ or $P(B \mid A_2)$.

EDIT: The question was already clear, but thank you for the example. That example is covered by what I wrote above, provided we make the right assumptions. Let
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \text{"The patient contracts Cancer Type 1."}\\
A_2 &= \text{"The patient contracts Cancer Type 2."}\\
B &= \text{"The patient dies of cancer."}
\end{align}
Let us assume $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conditionally independent given either $B$ or $B^c$. Then the above calculations give
$$
O(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{O(B \mid A_1) O(B \mid A_2)}{O(B)}.\tag{1}
$$
There are many things we can conclude from this. For instance, if
$$
O(B) < O(B \mid A_1) \le O(B \mid A_2),
$$
then $O(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2)$ is greater than both $O(B \mid A_1)$ and $O(B \mid A_2)$. If, additionally, we have $O(B) < 1$, then $O(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2) > O(B \mid A_1)^2$.
If we need to, we can convert Equation (1) from odds back to probabilities, obtaining
$$
P(B \mid A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{\alpha_1 \alpha_2}{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 + (1 - \alpha_1)(1 - \alpha_2)K},
$$
where $\alpha_1 = P(B \mid A_1)$, $\alpha_2 = P(B \mid A_2)$, and $K = O(B) = P(B)/(1 - P(B))$.
In summary, the general principle that you are suggesting is not true without further assumptions. The assumptions I described above are sufficient to make the principle work. I do not know of any references that discuss this particular question. If you cannot find any, then you can always work out the quantitative details using odds, as was done above. This should not require anything beyond what is in an introductory probability textbook. For example, Ross's A First Course in Probability discusses the odds formulas for conditional probability. See Equation (3.3) in Chapter 3.

I have added an example, in case you thought the question was unclear.

Thank you. I edited my answer.

The event $A_1\cap A_2$ may be much smaller than either of the events $A_1$ or $A_2$.  So even if most outcomes of the events are also outcomes of event $B$, that does not require that any outcomes of their intersection are.

$$\mathsf P(B\mid A_n)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A_n\cap A_1)}{\mathsf P(A_n\cap B)+\mathsf P(A_n\smallsetminus B)}$$
$\mathsf P(B\mid A_1)\approx 1$ and $\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)\approx 1$ means that their are only very improbable subsets of $A_1$ and $A_2$ that do not contain outcomes from $B$.
$$\mathsf P(B\mid A_1)\approx 1\implies\mathsf P(A_1\smallsetminus B)\approx 0\\\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)\approx 1\implies \mathsf P(A_2\smallsetminus B)\approx 0$$
However, it may be the case that those subsets are exactly the intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2$.  $$A_1\cap A_2 = (A_1\smallsetminus B)\cup(A_2\smallsetminus B)$$
Then the event $B$ cannot occur when the event $A_1\cap A_2$ does, so we will have:$$\mathsf P(B\mid A_1\cap A_2)=0$$
So we have constructed a counterexample, showing that $\mathsf P(B\mid A_1)\approx 1$ and $\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)\approx 1$ does not entail that $\mathsf P(B\mid A_1\cap A_2)\approx 1$.
